# Is window copyable in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need copy data of window and add to clipboard. I searched and I found nothing.

I reiceved data from rest api with html tags and I use html view for render the html tag. that's why I can't selectable text.

How to copy data of window or body of stateful widget? Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "data of window"?

Comment: I think he means to take a screenshot

Comment: This question isn't clear. Please modify.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy text from your app, you can use the `SelectableText` widget. There was recently a Widget of the Week video on it here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSU3ZXOs6hc&vl=en

There isn't a way to copy images or other data except for text, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following package to capture a screenshot.

Add the following to install

```
dependencies:
  screenshot: ^0.1.1
```

Then import it

`import 'package:screenshot/screenshot.dart';`

Example can be found here [Screenshot Example](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot#-readme-tab-)

References

- [screenshot package](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot)